# Unrecognized selector sent to destinationViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, segue

`UITableView` in my app is managed using `NSFetchedResultsController` and I want to implement Master-Detail behaviour but everytime I tap on a cell I get this `-[UIViewController setActivity:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x176a7660` error...

I don't know what is going on because my code is based on Apple's Master-Detail demo app.
Here is `prepareForSegue`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"activitySegue"]) {
        ActivityDetailsViewController *advc = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Activity *activity = (Activity *)[[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [advc setActivity:activity];
    }
}
```

And of course, there is declared `@property` in **destinationViewController**. I think that there could be something with this `NSManagedObject` and it is not passed properly to destination... But this is only my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the name of the view controller class in your storyboard for the detail view controller is not set, so an instance of `UIViewController` is created instead of an instance of `ActivityDetailsViewController`.

Set the name of the view controller in the story board to `ActivityDetailsViewController`.

Comment: I thought I'd never make this mistake... And I was mistaken! Thanks for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue in this line 
`Activity *activity = (Activity *)[[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];` Is this returning activity object ?